# Identity Server 3 multiple LogoutUris for same client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I have an MVC application which is multi tenant, differentiated by domain name:

```
app.tenant1.com

app.tenant2.com
```

And I have a single Client in IdentityServer (hybrid flow) with
with

```
RedirectUris = [http://app.tenant1.com, http://app.tenant2.com]

PostLogoutRedirectUris = [http://app.tenant1.com, http://app.tenant2.com]
```

But Logout uri only allows for a string value, not a list of strings

```
LogoutUri = "http://app.tenant1.com/home/SignoutCleanup";
```

My problem is that when I singout from **app.tenant2.com** I want the LogoutUri to be "http://app.tenant2.com/home/signoutcleanup"

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

PS: Is there a way to pass data to IS3 in the SingoutMessage? Similar to how we pass data in the acr_values ?

PPS: I've implemented a CustomEventService and log the user logins. Is there also a way of logging the Log out events ?

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

I see that this is the url that's called in order to generate the iframes which in turn call the signout for all apps

/core/connect/endsessioncallback

Is there a way to intercept this url and make changes to it's response?

Answer (score 0):

Given the limitation of cookies being scoped to hostnames, you could change how you configure this client to be multiple clients instead. The other idea is to use a host-level cookie to keep track of the tenant, and then use host-level signout cleanup URL.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a way of intercepting this url call "/core/connect/endsessioncallback" that IS3 is making in order to generate the iframes for the signout and perhaps there I could change the clients signout urls that are being called?

Comment: "The other idea is to use a host-level cookie to keep track of the tenant, and then use host-level signout cleanup URL." I don't fully understand how this would work. Can you give me some more info, please ?